# Display images from a folder using jquery/bootsrap as and when the folder is being populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am very very new to UI. So this question might look like a repeated one, but I frankly couldn't find an answer to this.

My application is running a background thread which downloads some images and stores it in a folder say images . I need to display these images in UI as and when the images are getting populated in folder. How should I proceed? I am using jQuery and Twitter bootstrap framework.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to address this on a client side alone. Ability for a client to access server's filesystem would be a serious security issue. You'll need to do some server-side coding to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This code will check if there are present image .png in a directory and if there are it will show they. Modify it for your purpose. To check when the folder is getting populated you can use a function timer for this code. There are two options, you can use **delay()** of jquery, or **setTimeout()** of basic javascript.

```
var dir = "Src/themes/base/images/";
var fileextension = ".png";
$.ajax({
    //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
        //List all .png file names in the page
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
            var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
            $("body").append("<img src='" + dir + filename + "'>");
        });
    }
});
```